# WPF Textbox VerticalContentAlignment Not Working

Tags: wpf, xaml

Can someone explain to me why `VerticalContentAlignment` does not appear to be working on the 3 textboxes inside the `Dockpanel`?

Text is aligned to the top and none of the values for `VerticalContentAlignment` have any effect. I've tried removing all margin and padding as well as messing with the `VerticalAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` properties of the textboxes as well as all parent controls.

Searching online returned minimal results and none of them seemed relevant to my scenario.

Here's my XAML:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource Primary}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="45" />
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="55" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Content="Opacity Width:" Foreground="#FFF" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"></Label>

            <TextBox Background="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" BorderBrush="#DFE3E9" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="#67737C" Margin="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{Binding OpacitiesWidth}" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="50" />

            <Label Content="Opacity Height:" Foreground="#FFF" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" />

            <TextBox Background="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" BorderBrush="#DFE3E9" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="#67737C" Margin="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{Binding OpacitiesHeight}" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="50" />

            <Label Content="Brightness Factor:" Foreground="#FFF" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16"></Label>

            <TextBox Background="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" BorderBrush="#DFE3E9" BorderThickness="0" Foreground="#67737C" Margin="5" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{Binding OpacitiesBrightnessFactor}" Padding="0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="50" />

            <controls:FlatButton DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="{x:Null}" ColorHover="{x:Null}" ColorPressed="{x:Null}" FontFamily="/Resources/#fontello" 
                                   Foreground="#8F96A1" ForegroundHover="#8F96A1" FontSize="20" Content="&#xe8a4;" Width="50" BorderThickness="0" 
                                   Command="{Binding CommandRandomize}" />
        </DockPanel>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0">
            <ListView Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Opacities}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">                                    
                                    <ContentPresenter />                                    
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
                                    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Margin="5">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Fill}" Width="64" Height="64">

                            </Rectangle>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Border>

        <controls:FlatButton Grid.Row="3" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Background="{StaticResource Secondary}" ColorHover="{StaticResource SecondaryLight}" ColorPressed="{StaticResource Secondary}"
                             Foreground="#FFF" ForegroundHover="#8F96A1" FontSize="20" Content="Debug" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding CommandDebug}" Margin="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**EDIT**

If I move my code into a fresh WPF solution `VerticalContentAlignment` works just fine. Something is wrong with my solution but I'm not sure what.

**EDIT2**

The problem is my custom scrollbar style. Can anyone help me figure how to edit it so it doesn't interfere with my textboxes?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>    

<Style x:Key="ScrollThumbs" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Rectangle1" Background="{StaticResource PrimaryLight}" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Transparent" />
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Rectangle1" Property="MinHeight" Value="450" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource ScrollbarTrack}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="False">
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                </Track>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource PrimaryDark}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="0" IsDirectionReversed="True">
                                    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageUp" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <Track.Thumb>
                                        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollThumbs}" />
                                    </Track.Thumb>
                                    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PageDown" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Opacity="0" Focusable="false" />
                                    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                </Track>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code, the texts are showing in the center of TextBox. Are you sure you are not applying some custom style/template to the TextBoxes somewhere not shown here?

Comment: I have a custom style that overrides the focus behavior of textboxes but it shouldn't effect alignment and I did test my code without it with the same result. My best guess is something in my solution is bugged but I don't know what or where to begin looking.

Comment: Post the style here if you have trouble, so people can take a look and give you hint. I am guessing that you defined a new `Template` that does not pass the `VerticalContentAlignment` to the `Template`'s `VerticalAlignment`.

Comment: The style is irrelevant to my issue. My other solutions use it and I don't have this problem and I've also removed the style and it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you have an override somewhere for `ScrollViewer` that would be overriding the Content_Host ScrollViewer that's default in any TextBox template? A style template absolutely would be relative to your issue, the trick is figuring out which one is your culprit...property inheritance can be your friend or your enemy.

Comment: Oh, I'm not saying a style isn't relevant, just the one for the textbox wasn't. You are spot on though, it was the custom scrollbar template I made for the project that was causing the problem.

Now I need to figure out how to fix my scrollbar template because it is required for this program.

Comment: @ChrisW. I've added my scrollbar style to my question, could you take a look and point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Andronomos if it were me, I would give your custom style `x:Key` name and apply it explicitly as a `StaticResource` (Style="StaticResource NewStyleName") just to instances that require it since by only defining `TargetType` of `ScrollViewer` you're overriding the template wherever scrollviewer is used (which is in multiple controls including TextBox) to avoid future troubleshooting/maintenance issues. Otherwise, bind `VerticalAlignment` on the `ScrollPresenter` to a default `Setter` on your style template as `VerticalContentAlignment` but that's only what you're missing for this scenario...

Comment: Oh and PS, if you're going to override something like ScrollViewer (that has sub controls in it already) it's a good idea to look at defaults and make sure you include any default stuff you may be missing....like a direct way to set a property on a sub control that would need it. Cheers :)

Comment: @ChrisW. The reason I did it this way was because I was overriding the scrollbars of a listview. How would I apply a static resource to the listview if the style is targeting the scrollviewer?

Comment: Whew, this ones getting long out of just a comments thing and out of scope of the original question but no worries, you can inherit just to the instance of ListView via like (pseudo) `<ListView><ListView.Resources><Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" BasedOn="{StaticResource NewScrollViewerStyleKeyName}"/></ListView.Resources></ListView>` then all ScrollViewer type children of that ListView will inherit the style template you desire. Or apply the same directly to the base ListView template and it will hit everywhere ListView is used by default.

Comment: @ChrisW. Ah, okay that makes sense. Could you please post an answer that I can accept as you have solved my original problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right sorry for the delayed response, been an interesting couple weeks. Anyhow let's go ahead and post something to help future readers avoid some of the comment clutter that might help somebody in the future (I'm a big fan of the propagation of learning and helping) sooo...

Originally your issue is actually a really common one, especially when somebody is maybe new to things like DOM & Property Inheritance. I see this most commonly with folks who maybe spend most of their time in the code side as opposed to the presentation layer. Like in this scenario folks that may be awesome at C# (which by itself takes a lot of space in the old brain box) but generally just hack it through on the layout side. Which is why I usually advocate separating those parts of the presentation layer between team members to leverage each others strengths since either area requires a lot of knowledge / experience retention to be truly proficient.

Anyhow, when using various CLI / SDK controls it's important to remember the cascading inheritance model these little fellas are ruled by to help encourage D.R.Y. development. So for example if you're using say a `RadioButton` it's important it derives from the `ToggleButton` class up the family tree. Or in this instance, a `TextBox` which includes a `ScrollViewer` as child element within its base style template.

This is an example of shared resources that can quickly play a culprit between one another when we maybe edit/customize one but forget it still has to play nice with the other.

So by doing something like;

```
<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
  <!-- Our customizations necessary for our instance scenario here -->
</Style>
```

....then well depending on where this fella sits in the inheritance tree it could have an unwanted effect down the line for other controls such as `TextBox`, `ListBox`, `ListView`, `TreeView`, `Menu`, or a number of controls that might be counting on a `ScrollViewer` as well for part of their operations.

Now generally if this new template you would create would need to be applied multiple places without interfering with other elements requiring the original default style template to control it than an easy route would be to just explicitly define this style override where we need it such as;

```
In a resource dictionary;

<Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" x:Key="OurSuperCoolNewScrollViewerStyleTemplate">
      <!-- Our customizations necessary for our instance scenario here -->    
</Style>

Then in at the instance declared as a StaticResource or a DynamicResource respectively;

<ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource OurSuperCoolNewScrollViewerStyleTemplate}"/>
```

So that can control where exactly we're going to apply our new resource instead of justifying it as an inheritable override by simply declaring `TargetType` which will hit any instances of the same type. Except that can become tedious and unnecessary when say we have multiple of the same elements requiring the same style but we just want those to automatically inherit without implicit declaration? Well then we leverage inheritance modeling via `BasedOn` like;

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" 
             BasedOn="{StaticResource OurSuperCoolNewScrollViewerStyleTemplate}"/>
   </StackPanel.Resources>

   <ScrollViewer/>
   <TextBox/>
   <ListBox/>

</StackPanel>
```

Wherein this scenario all the children of that `StackPanel` with an embedded control of type `ScrollViewer` would inherit the new `Style` template.

However there's a caveat to this scenario. Sometimes plopping a `Style` template in a `ResourceDictionary` isn't the best practice since that `ResourceDictionary` is going to load everything in it at runtime. So say we run into an instance where we need to perhaps apply just some minor changes to small area or single element which is rarely used. So in that case instead of bloating our `ResourceDictionary` further for no reason because it's just an adhoc rarely used scenario it can sometimes be better to apply the entire Style template implicitly for that one single instance such as;

```
<TextBox>
   <TextBox.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer">
          <!-- Our customizations necessary for our instance scenario here -->    
      </Style>
   </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Anyway, hope this helps and glad you found your culprit! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

The issue original described was caused by overwriting the ScrollViewer style and set a custom template. The custom template however was missing some properties in the ScrollContentPresenter.

```
Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll}"
```

See below for the corrected version:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Row="0" 
                                            Grid.Column="0" 
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll}" />
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" 
                               Grid.Row="0" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" 
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                               Orientation="Horizontal"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                               Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}"
                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```